# cap vs len of slice in golang

Tags: go, slice

What is the difference between cap and len of a slice in golang?

According to definition:

A slice has both a length and a capacity.

The length of a slice is the number of elements it contains.

The capacity of a slice is the number of elements in the underlying array, counting from the first element in the slice.

```
x := make([]int, 0, 5) // len(b)=0, cap(b)=5
```

Does the len mean non null values only?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

A slice is an abstraction that uses an array under the covers.

`cap` tells you the capacity of the underlying array. `len` tells you how many items are in the array.

The slice abstraction in Go is very nice since it will resize the underlying array for you, plus in Go arrays cannot be resized so slices are almost always used instead.

Example:

```
s := make([]int, 0, 3)
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    s = append(s, i)
    fmt.Printf("cap %v, len %v, %p\n", cap(s), len(s), s)
}
```

Will output something like this:

```
cap 3, len 1, 0x1040e130
cap 3, len 2, 0x1040e130
cap 3, len 3, 0x1040e130
cap 6, len 4, 0x10432220
cap 6, len 5, 0x10432220
```

As you can see once the capacity is met, `append` will return a new slice with a larger capacity. On the 4th iteration you will notice a larger capacity and a new pointer address.

[Play example](https://play.golang.org/p/RhhsGgFYI1)

I realize you did not ask about arrays and append but they are pretty foundational in understanding the slice and the reason for the builtins.

Comment: Great answer.  The OP may not care anymore, but I can see this being helpful for a lot of people that may find it down the road.

Comment: @RandyHoward Thanks, I appreciate that. I find knowing that the pointer address changes to be quite important.

Comment: @jmaloney. This is very helpful.  One thing I'm still having trouble understanding is that the nil value for arrays and slices is zero (not nil or null) so, how can the length ever actually be different than the capacity. Shouldn't each element in a slice of capacity 3 have {1,0,0} in the first iteration...giving the len to be 3 not 1?  I mean if it's just convention, I don't understand the logic in that convention.  Am I just missing something or should I just accept it as is?

Comment: @BradEllis Arrays unlike slices do not have a nil value. When you create an array `var array [3]int` you are explicitly allocating the capacity and length of an array. When speaking of an array in Go the cap and len functions are the same. You need to remember that a slice in Go is a data type that utilizes an array but is not the array. So when you call `cap(someSlice)` you are checking the capacity or length of the underline array, but when you call `len(someSlice)` you are checking how many items you explicitly added to the slice. Exampe: https://play.golang.org/p/ahlHLkD4_Wt

Comment: go is doubling the `cap` when it reaches the cap.. why? is it a good thing ... e.g. to added `769` items array cap will be `1536`

Comment: @VikasBansal It's an optimization to avoid constant allocation. For instance say you were appending a bunch of items to a slice in a for loop, the performance would be terrible if you had to constantly re-allocate the memory for the underlining array.

Comment: when the size exceeds the capacity it doubles. i am not sure if it was working previously otherwise but now it just doubles.

Comment: @serkan I'm guessing one of the recent Go releases changed how append resized the underline array.

Comment: FYI, the cap scaling is based on the Fibonacci n-step number, and `len` is the base number,

Answer (score 13):

From the [source code](https://golang.org/src/builtin/builtin.go?s=5727:5747#L145):

```
// The len built-in function returns the length of v, according to its type:
//  Array: the number of elements in v.
//  Pointer to array: the number of elements in *v (even if v is nil).
//  Slice, or map: the number of elements in v; if v is nil, len(v) is zero.
//  String: the number of bytes in v.
//  Channel: the number of elements queued (unread) in the channel buffer;
//  if v is nil, len(v) is zero.
func len(v Type) int

// The cap built-in function returns the capacity of v, according to its type:
//  Array: the number of elements in v (same as len(v)).
//  Pointer to array: the number of elements in *v (same as len(v)).
//  Slice: the maximum length the slice can reach when resliced;
//  if v is nil, cap(v) is zero.
//  Channel: the channel buffer capacity, in units of elements;
//  if v is nil, cap(v) is zero.
func cap(v Type) int
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple explanation
Slice are self growing form of array so there are two main properties.

Length is total no of elements() the slice is having and can be used for looping through the elements we stored in slice. Also when we print the slice all elements till length gets printed.

Capacity is total no elements in underlying array, when you append more elements the length increases till capacity. After that any further append to slice causes the capacity to increase automatically(apprx double) and length by no of elements appended.

The real magic happens when you slice out sub slices from a slice where all the actual read/write happens on the underlaying array. So any change in sub slice will also change data both in original slice and underlying array. Where as any sub slices can have their own length and capacity.

Go through the below program carefully. It is a modified version of a golang tour [example](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/11)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    sorig := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    printSlice(sorig)

    // Slice the slice to give it zero length.
    s := sorig[:0]
    printSlice(s)

    // Extend its length.
    s = s[:4]
    s[2] = 555
    printSlice(s)

    // Drop its first two values.
    s = s[2:]
    printSlice(s)
    
    printSlice(sorig)
}

func printSlice(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}     

//Output
//len=6 cap=6 [2 3 5 7 11 13]
//len=0 cap=6 []
//len=4 cap=6 [2 3 555 7]
//len=2 cap=4 [555 7]
//len=6 cap=6 [2 3 555 7 11 13]
```