# What's the Go idiom for Python's list.pop() method?

Tags: list, go, slice

In Python, I have the following:

```python
i = series.index(s) # standard Python list.index() function
tmp = series.pop(i)
blah = f(tmp)
series.append(tmp)
```

In converting this to Go, I am looking for a similar way of retrieving an item from a slice by index, doing something with it, then putting the original item at the end of my slice.

From [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks), I have arrived at the following:

```
i = Index(series, s) // my custom index function...
tmp, series = series[i], series[i+1:]
blah := f(tmp)
series = append(series, tmp)
```

But this fails at the end of lists:

```
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
```

How would I idiomatically translate this `slice.pop()` into Go?

Comment: What's in `i` and what's `cap` and `len` of `series`?

Comment: It would help if you shared your `Index` function. The wiki you listed also has a recipe to pop an element and get the rest of the slice.

Comment: Index returns an integer, `i`, corresponding to the index of `series` where the value `s` is located.

Comment: @Mittenchops if it returned that you wouldn't have had a panic

Comment: If you find yourself calling `list.index` or `list.pop` with an index argument in Python, it's a sign you may be using the wrong data structure. A set or dict (a map in Go) may be more appropriate, or possibly something else.

Comment: Also, you're not using `blah`.

Comment: Thanks, @user2357112, this is not a python question.  Just worried about Go.  I am using blah, just not in the example for simplicity.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The ["Cut" trick](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#cut) in the linked document does what you want:

```
xs := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

i := 0 // Any valid index, however you happen to get it.
x := xs[i]
xs = append(xs[:i], xs[i+1:]...)
// Now "x" is the ith element and "xs" has the ith element removed.
```

Note that if you try to make a one-liner out of the get-and-cut operations you'll get unexpected results due to the tricky behavior of multiple assignments in which functions are called *before other expressions are evaluated*:

```
i := 0
x, xs := xs[i], append(xs[:i], xs[i+1:]...)
// XXX: x=2, xs=[]int{2, 3, 4, 5}
```

You can work around by wrapping the element access operation in any function call, such as the identity function:

```
i := 0
id := func(z int) { return z }
x, xs := id(xs[i]), append(xs[:i], xs[i+1:]...)
// OK: x=1, xs=[]int{2, 3, 4, 5}
```

However, at that point it's probably more clear to use separate assignments.

For completeness, a "cut" function and its usage could look like this:

```
func cut(i int, xs []int) (int, []int) {
  y := xs[i]
  ys := append(xs[:i], xs[i+1:]...)
  return y, ys
}

t, series := cut(i, series)
f(t)
series = append(series, t)
```

Comment: Thanks, the language of "cut" I didn't get, but this worked.  I would never have guessed the ...

Answer (score 9):

If you want to write a function that does pop() in a similar way to python then you'll have to pass in a pointer to the object so the object can be modified, as pop both returns the value and alters the list

```
func pop(alist *[]int) int {
   f:=len(*alist)
   rv:=(*alist)[f-1]
   *alist=(*alist)[:f-1]
   return rv
}

func main() {
n:=[]int{1,2,3,4,5}
fmt.Println(n)
last:=pop(&n)
fmt.Println("last is",last)
fmt.Printf("list of n is now %v\n", n)
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use `append` here? Would `*alist=(*alist)[:f-1]` be wrong or less efficient?

Comment: I agree Nicolas, the append seems to be unnecessary.  I retested it and it worked fine.  I looked at the append implementation (briefly) and couldn't see any magic gotchas.  Updated answer

Answer (score 3):

You can declare`type intSlice []int` and you can declare method `pop()` using that pointer receiver: `func (l *intSlice) pop() int`. Then you can call `.pop()` on instance of `intSlice` object. This becomes stylistically more similar to Python.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type intSlice []int

func (l *intSlice) pop() int {
    length := len(*l)
    lastEle := (*l)[length-1]
    *l = (*l)[:length-1]
    return lastEle
}

func main() {

    mySlice := intSlice{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

    popped := mySlice.pop()

    fmt.Println(popped)
    fmt.Println(mySlice)

    popped = mySlice.pop()

    fmt.Println(popped)
    fmt.Println(mySlice)

}
```

Result:

```
6
[1 2 3 4 5]
5
[1 2 3 4]
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9UYj5G5V9k5)

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to create a function that takes a pointer to an int slice which modifies the argument to remove the last value and return it:

```go
func pop(xs *[]int) int {
  x := (*xs)[len(*xs)-1]   // Store the last value to return.
  *xs = (*xs)[:len(*xs)-1] // Remove the last value from the slice.
  return x
}
```

[For example (Go Playground)](https://go.dev/play/p/mjh6XqDfz2d):

```
xs := []int{1, 2, 3} // => xs=[1, 2, 3]
x := pop(&xs)        // => xs=[1, 2],   x=3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a direct equivalent of "pop()" ... but you can do something like this:

> [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/13)
>
> Slices can be created with the built-in make function; this is how
>   you create dynamically-sized arrays.
>
> The make function allocates a zeroed array and returns a slice that
>   refers to that array:
>
> `a := make([]int, 5)  // len(a)=5`
>
> To specify a capacity, pass a third argument to make:
>
> `b := make([]int, 0, 5) // len(b)=0, cap(b)=5`
>
> `b = b[:cap(b)] // len(b)=5, cap(b)=5`
>
> `b = b[1:]      // len(b)=4, cap(b)=4`

See also:

- https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals
- [cap vs len of slice in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668053/cap-vs-len-of-slice-in-golang)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something similar to what paulsm4 suggested:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := []int{1,2,3,4,5}
    i,b := pop(a)
    fmt.Println(i,b) // 5 [1 2 3 4]
}

func pop(a []int) (int,[]int) {
    return a[len(a)-1],a[:len(a)-1]
}
```

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dvdw48Y4TRJ)

Comment: that isn't quite how pop() works in python or perl or several other implementations. 
 The input list is modified - see my answer below

Comment: @Vorsprung yeah, using a pointer you wouldn't have to return the array, smart way to do it.