# How to get the number of items from a structure sub field using reflect in go

Tags: go, slice

I have some issues when getting the number of items from a sub field in a slice struct through `reflect` package.

This is how I'm trying to get the number of items from `Items`

```
func main() {

  type Items struct {
      Name    string `json:"name"`
      Present bool   `json:"present"`
  }

  type someStuff struct {
      Fields string     `json:"fields"`
      Items    []Items `json:"items"`
  }

  type Stuff struct {
      Stuff []someStuff `json:"stuff"`
  }

  some_stuff := `{
                  "stuff": [
                     {
                       "fields": "example",
                       "items": [
                         { "name": "book01", "present": true },
                         { "name": "book02", "present": true },
                         { "name": "book03", "present": true }                                        
                       ]
                     }
                   ]
                }`

  var variable Stuff

  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(some_stuff), &variable)
  if err != nil {
      panic(err)
  }

  //I want to get the number of items in my case 3
  NumItems := reflect.ValueOf(variable.Stuff.Items)

}
```

This is the error:

```
variable.Items undefined (type []Stuff has no field or method Items)
```

I'm unsure if I can retrieve the number of items like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cap vs len of slice in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668053/cap-vs-len-of-slice-in-golang)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I'm looking to resolve the issue just using `reflect` if possible.

Comment: The code will not even compile because `variable` is of type `[]Stuff` and type `[]Stuff` has no `Stuff` therefore the expression `variable.Stuff` is illegal.

Comment: Another problem is that `some_stuff` contains a JSON object while the target variable called `variable` is of type `[]Stuff` (i.e. a slice of `Stuff`). You cannot unmarshal JSON objects into Go slices. If your code would compile, it would fail at runtime with the `panic(err)` from `json.Unmarshal`.

Comment: The `NumField` from `reflect` returns the *number of fields* of a struct type. It does not return the number of elements in a slice. For that you should use [`Len`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.19#Value.Len) and *note* that `Len` is a method of `reflect.Value` and not of `reflect.Type` therefore you should not be using `reflect.TypeOf` if you want to inspect a specific instance.

Comment: @mkopriva can you show an example on how would you do that base on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already fixed the issue.

In order to get the number of sub fields we can make use of `Len()` from `reflect.ValueOf`.

The code now is getting the number of Items:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {

    type Items struct {
        Name    string `json:"name"`
        Present bool   `json:"present"`
    }

    type someStuff struct {
        Fields string  `json:"fields"`
        Items  []Items `json:"items"`
    }

    type Stuff struct {
        Stuff []someStuff `json:"stuff"`
    }

    some_stuff := `{
                  "stuff": [
                     {
                       "fields": "example",
                       "items": [
                         { "name": "book01", "present": true },
                         { "name": "book02", "present": true },
                         { "name": "book03", "present": true }                                        
                       ]
                     }
                   ]
                }`

    var variable Stuff

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(some_stuff), &variable)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //I want to get the number of items in my case 3
    t := reflect.ValueOf(variable.Stuff[0].Items)
    fmt.Println(t.Len())

}
```

```
Output: 3
```